# on append data with ajax call returns only first row from database in jquery and php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working with jquery and php to get data from database onchange particular selection.
My ajax call works fine.but it shows only first row from table.

my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({

          method: "GET",
           dataType: 'json',
           url:"getdata.php?id="+emp_id,
              success:function (response){
                     $.each(response, function( index, value ) {
                              $(".bodytable").empty();
                              $("table.table").append("<tr><td>" + response.emp_name + "</td><td>"  + "</td><td><input type='file'></td></tr>");

                      });
              },  
      });
```

and below is my query for the same :

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $explodeVal = $_GET['id'];



    $sql = "SELECT * FROM emp_master_new as emn 
                INNER JOIN emp_info as cti ON emn.id=cti.id 
                WHERE cti.com_id = '".$explodeVal."' ";
    $execute = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($execute,MYSQLI_ASSOC);


    echo  json_encode($row);
}
```

on success response i only get [object object].

Comment: can you show us your output before json_encode line?

Comment: Hi, did you tried to change `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($execute,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
` to `$row= $execute->fetch_assoc();` ? And then echo `json_encode($row)`;

Comment: The function `mysqli_fetch_array()` only returns 1 row at a time. Check out the top note to see how to get more rows: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: @hemant `{"id":"5","com_id":"2","emp_name":"john batista","address":"TEST ADDRESS","phone":"9856457812","dob":"2019-01-22","nino":"2211","pension_provider":null,"pension_amount":null,"id_file_name":"","address_file_name":"","modified_date":"2019-01-22 00:00:00","created_at":"2019-02-04 08:48:53","updated_at":"2019-01-22"}` this is my json it shows only one row

Comment: use `mysqli_fetch_all($execute,MYSQLI_ASSOC);` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()`

Comment: @catcon it shows me undefined

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_all()` available with `mysqlnd` only, probably your server doesn't have it enabled, then use the link newUserName02 provide.

Comment: for now i am able to get all data from database. but now in ajax response it shows only last row from db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get all records from php file by using `mysqli_fetch_all` as below:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $explodeVal = $_GET['id'];



    $sql = "SELECT * FROM emp_master_new as emn 
                INNER JOIN emp_info as cti ON emn.id=cti.id 
                WHERE cti.com_id = '".$explodeVal."' ";
    $execute = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_all($execute,MYSQLI_ASSOC);


    echo  json_encode($row);
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks bro but i resolve my this issue earlier. my problem is inside each function. it shows me last record only. for this i have created another question too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54703116/ajax-response-display-only-last-row-from-database-in-jquery-and-php

Comment: Replied on that as well.