# ajax response display only last row from database in jquery and php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

> I am working on php and jquery with one dropdown with companies. i
>   want to display particular companies all employees on select that
>   company. for this i am using ajax response with jquery. my reponse
>   shows me perfect data but my each function is not working correctly.
>   it shows me only last record from db.

```
$.ajax({

          method: "GET",
           dataType: 'json',
           url:"getdata.php?id="+emp_id,
              success:function (response){
                     $.each(response, function( index, value ) {
                              $(".bodytable").empty();
                              $("table.table").append("<tr><td>" + value.emp_name + "</td><td>"  + "</td><td><input type='file'></td></tr>");

                      });
              },  
      });
```

My response shows me correct data. 
for e.g where i am having 2 employees it shows me `[object object][object object]`

if i am having 1 employee its shows me `[object object].`

But its not working inside each function. inside each function it only shows last record from database.

My html of company list:

```
<select  id="billing_com" name="billing_com" >
        <option>--Select Customer--</option>
        <?php   foreach($com_data as $key=>$eachcomData){
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $eachcomData['com_id'];?>"  <?php   
                    if(isset($_GET['id'])){ echo ($upload['com_name'] == $eachcomData['com_id'])?'selected=selected':'abc';   }    ?> >

                <?php echo $eachcomData['com_name']; ?>

            </option>



             <?php }?>

        </select>
```

code that will call after ajax response:

```
 <table class="tabledata">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Employee Name</th>
                            <th>Attach Payslip</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="bodytable">

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: Show your php code. The returned value is object, instead of array.

Comment: `$(".bodytable").empty();` makes empty on each iteration, so put it outside loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make empty your table outside the each loop. Like this:

```
$.ajax({
          method: "GET",
           dataType: 'json',
           url:"getdata.php?id="+emp_id,
              success:function (response){
                     $(".bodytable").empty();
                     $.each(response, function( index, value ) {

                              $("table.table").append("<tr><td>" + value.emp_name + "</td><td>"  + "</td><td><input type='file'></td></tr>");

                      });
              },  
      });
```

Also you are appending directly to table. I prefer to append in tbody like below:

```
$(".bodytable").append("<tr><td>" + value.emp_name + "</td><td>"  + "</td><td><input type='file'></td></tr>");
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: it works for me. but i have to select that particular company twice. on 2nd selection it shows me 2 employees.

Comment: Can you add your complete HTML as well?

Comment: Can you aslo update your jquery cod? Add code when you get change event of select. Cause all other code seems very fine.